# How to catch GroovyShell output?

Tags: java, groovy, groovyshell

I create a groovy engine with the GroovyShell class.
Then I run a bunch of statements with the "evaluate" method.
Is there a way to catch the output of the engine so I can get "println" calls output?
Currently it goes to stdout although it is a swing application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just assign your custom Writer (eg. StringWriter) to `out` property in the binding and pass it to the GroovyShell.

```
def binding = new Binding();
binding.setProperty("out", new YourWriter())
new GroovyShell(binding);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `scriptBaseClass` with a `println` method and you are free to operate on top of the value. Remember the user still can do `System.out.println`, but [you can blacklist](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/control/customizers/SecureASTCustomizer.html) it, if needed.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration

def script = """
  a = 10
  println a
  println "echo"
"""

abstract class Printer extends Script {
  void println(obj) {
    this.binding.printed << obj
  }
}

def config = new CompilerConfiguration(scriptBaseClass: Printer.class.name)
def binding = new Binding([printed: []])

new GroovyShell(this.class.classLoader, binding, config).evaluate script

assert binding.variables.printed.contains( 10 )
assert binding.variables.printed.contains( "echo" )
```

Comment: Thanks. Since I do it from java code, do you know how should I define the Printer class (Java code)?

Comment: Since you are writing the `Printer` in Java, are you having trouble with the `this.binding`?

Comment: Thanks, I've figured it out.